# Search for a string in an XML file

Tags: java, xml, string, full-text-search

I need to search for a string in an XML file. I have developed the following function for this

```
public  boolean IsTextInFile(String sFileName, String sVerifyText )
     {
        File file = new File(sFileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String sCurrLine = "", sAllLines = "";
        boolean bStatus = false;

        while ((sCurrLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sAllLines += sCurrLine;
        }       
        if (sAllLines.contains(sVerifyText)) {
            bStatus = true;     
        }
        reader.close();     
        return bStatus;
    }
```

now the string is like this which I want to search for in the xml file

```xml
<docAttr type=\"abc\" name=\"pqr\">44</docAttr>
```

it always returning false.

I have tried with substring of given one

when I am trying for `<docAttr type=\"abc\"` its returning true and `name=\"pqr\">44</docAttr>` for this also its returning true . but when I am taking it as a full

```xml
<docAttr type=\"abc\" name=\"pqr\">44</docAttr>
```

its returning false.

Moreover I am directly able to search my string using find in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I suggest you write a small unit test to aid debugging

Comment: There might be a tab (`\t`) not a space between `type=\"abc\"` and `name=\"pqr\"`.

Comment: what is your search string?

Comment: my Actual searching string is <docAttrtype="abc" name="pqr">44</docAttr>

Comment: @Arun may be try to use xml parsers like DOM or SAX?

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak  +1 to the first good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the order of XML attributes are irrelevant and also that whitespace between attributes can vary. This makes string searching very frail. Try use XPath instead. Since you are using Java, that would come for free.

For example, to select all <docAttr> elements that has the specified values for the attributes type and name and that contains the text "44":

```
//docAttr[@type='abc' and @name='pqr' and text()='44']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String xml = xml.toString(); //or whatever methods it uses to convert.

//check if string has.
boolean doesContain = xml.contains("my word/s");
```